# why is name.startswith('a') returning True on the name 'barry'?

Tags: python, filter, startswith

I am trying to learn how to use the .startswith() method and also the filter() function. For some reason I am not getting the result I expected. I don't know if I am misunderstanding 'startswith' or 'filter'.

here is the code i used

```
names = ['aaron','anthony','tom','henry','barry']
def start_a(names):
    for name in names:
        if name.startswith('a'):
            return True
            
            
        
print(list(filter(start_a, names)))
```

i was expecting to get ['aaron', 'anthony'] however i got ['aaron', 'anthony', 'barry']

does anyone know where i went wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`start_a()` is looping over the characters in the name, because it just receives one list element as its parameter. So it's actually checking whether the name contains `a`, not whether it starts with `a`.

`filter()` does the looping over the list for you, you don't need another loop in the function.

```
def start_a(name):
    return name.startswith('a')
```

Answer (score 3):

`filter` calls `start_a` for each name in the `names` list. When you iterate that name in the `for` loop, you get individual characters, not the name. As a result, you return `True` for any name with an `a` in it. You can see that with a well-positioned print:

```
names = ['aaron','anthony','tom','henry','barry']
def start_a(names):
    print("start_a")
    for name in names:
        print("  checking", repr(name))
        if name.startswith('a'):
            print("TRUE!")
            return True          
        
print(list(filter(start_a, names)))
```

Output

```
start_a
  checking 'a'
TRUE!
start_a
  checking 'a'
TRUE!
start_a
  checking 't'
  checking 'o'
  checking 'm'
start_a
  checking 'h'
  checking 'e'
  checking 'n'
  checking 'r'
  checking 'y'
start_a
  checking 'b'
  checking 'a'
TRUE!
['aaron', 'anthony', 'barry']
```

You are checking a single name on each call to `start_a`, so rename that variable and remove the loop. Since you only call `startswith` once, you can also get rid of the `if`.

```
names = ['aaron','anthony','tom','henry','barry']
def start_a(name):
    return name.startswith('a')
           
            
        
print(list(filter(start_a, names)))
```

This is one of those cases where an anonymous function comes in handy. You could also write

```
names = ['aaron','anthony','tom','henry','barry']       
print(list(filter(lambda name: name.startswith('a'), names)))
```

You could also write it as a list comprehension

```
names = ['aaron','anthony','tom','henry','barry']       
print([name for name in names if name.startswith('a')])
```